# nodejs sails : the sails.sid variable return undefined

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sid

I cant access to sails sid by default `sails.sid` variable

here is my config.session

```
module.exports.session = {

  secret: 'f67cffdb3b2dc70c200a9e8bf3a16cac',

  // isSessionDisabled: function (req){
  //   return !!req.path.match(req._sails.LOOKS_LIKE_ASSET_RX);
  // },

};
```

when i do `console.log(sails.sid)` i get undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session object can be accessed through the **request** object e.g.

```
req.session
```

and also through the global **sails** object

```
sails.session
```